# How Do I set one kendo datepicker value another kendo datepicker

Tags: jquery

For example I have startdate, enddate kendo datepicker. If I am changing startdate datepicker value automatically I have to set startdate value to the enddate datepicker value.

Please help me how to set this value.

Comment: Kendo datepicker has a `.value()` method for getting and setting. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/api.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913525/kendo-date-picker-max-date/28914159#28914159